# Heroku H15 Errors Using Java NIO Directly and Netty

Tags: java, heroku, netty, nio

This is a problem for us using [vlingo-http](https://github.com/vlingo/vlingo-http) backed by [vlingo-wire](https://github.com/vlingo/vlingo-wire), which was making direct use of Java NIO. We thought we were facing the [infamous Netty Java NIO epoll bug](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/327) that was fixed by Netty, so we applied Netty's fix to `vlingo-wire`. This didn't work. We finally gave up trying to solve it with direct NIO and even with incorporating Netty's fix. Thus, we switched to Netty in place of NIO, which works everywhere else, but not on Heroku.

Using Netty and some fine-grained logging we saw that for each request the server definitely replies. But for some reason the reply does not get past the Heroku router. For example:

```
2020-04-06T20:50:13.896574+00:00 app[web.1]: 20:50:13.896 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] DEBUG i.v.w.f.b.n.s.NettyInboundHandler - Request received
2020-04-06T20:50:13.896929+00:00 app[web.1]: 20:50:13.896 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] DEBUG i.n.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x1efddaa2, L:/172.18.27.14:59829 - R:/10.11.43.12:20716] READ COMPLETE
2020-04-06T20:50:13.897026+00:00 app[web.1]: Retrieving operations and...
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898394+00:00 app[web.1]: 20:50:13.898 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] DEBUG i.n.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x1efddaa2, L:/172.18.27.14:59829 - R:/10.11.43.12:20716] WRITE: 148B
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898395+00:00 app[web.1]: +-------------------------------------------------+
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898396+00:00 app[web.1]: |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898397+00:00 app[web.1]: +--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898397+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000000| 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0a |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898397+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000010| 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70 |Content-Type: ap|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898399+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000020| 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 76 6e 64 2e 63 61 |plication/vnd.ca|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898400+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000030| 6c 63 75 6c 61 74 69 6f 6e 2b 6a 73 6f 6e 3b 76 |lculation+json;v|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898400+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000040| 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 31 2e 31 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 |ersion=1.1.Conte|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898400+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000050| 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 35 33 0a 0a 5b |nt-Length: 53..[|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898401+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000060| 0a 20 20 22 41 44 44 49 54 49 4f 4e 22 2c 0a 20 |.  "ADDITION",. |
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898401+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000070| 20 22 53 55 42 54 52 41 43 54 49 4f 4e 22 2c 0a | "SUBTRACTION",.|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898401+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000080| 20 20 22 4d 55 4c 54 49 50 4c 49 43 41 54 49 4f |  "MULTIPLICATIO|
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898402+00:00 app[web.1]: |00000090| 4e 22 0a 5d                                     |N".]            |
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898402+00:00 app[web.1]: +--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898467+00:00 app[web.1]: 20:50:13.898 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] DEBUG i.n.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x1efddaa2, L:/172.18.27.14:59829 - R:/10.11.43.12:20716] FLUSH
2020-04-06T20:50:13.898847+00:00 app[web.1]: 20:50:13.898 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] TRACE i.v.w.f.b.n.s.NettyInboundHandler - Reply sent
```

The conclusion was that perhaps we were not closing the client socket properly (even though using `curl` has the same problems). In any case we tried server socket eager closing to close the socket right after a response to an HTTP request. The assumption was that maybe the close would flush socket buffers (small responses). This also didn't work for us.

All of the above worked from the beginning on direct AWS use, and continues to work there.

We are currently looking into some ideas we got about timeouts and DNS configuration, but so far it's not panning out.

At this point we are stuck and don't know what to do or try next. We would sure like to support Heroku. If you have any clues to share we would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hey there, I'm working for Heroku. Is there a way to reproduce this? Some sample project that triggers the issue on Heroku? I'd like to take a deeper look at this if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Malax You can see the example used in the following repo, with steps in the README. https://github.com/danilo-ambrosio/heroku-microservice Here are more steps: Once the Procfile already exists, all you need to do is to deploy it on Heroku and perform a simple GET request on [app-name].herokuapp.com/calculations/operations. The app handles successfully, however, the request hangs until an H15 error happens.

Comment: Hi @Malax Did the above ^^^ code and steps  help?